# how can I prepare 5-nitro-2-indanone?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I want to make 5-hydroxy-2-indanone, so I need make 5-nitro-2-indanone first.But I can find any documents for reference. please give me some suggestion, thanks

Comment: I would not limit my options looking for the nitro-substituted precursor while other strategies might be available too. Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/65040

Answer (score 1):

Drawing on Klaus's comment and reference to the preparation of 2-indanone, I suggest starting with the commercially available 3,4-dimethyl anisole. Bromination under radical conditions (non-polar solvent, AIBN, arc lamp) with NBS should give the bis-bromomethyl compound. Reaction with the anion of dithiane with 2eq of strong base should give the dithiane of 5-methoxy-2-indanone. Deprotection with boron tribromide reveals the OH and dithiane removal by acid hydrolysis or Hg++ gives 5-hydroxy-2-indanone.

Comment: From personal experience, 3,4-dimethylanisole may be activated enough to under electrophilic bromination even under nonpolar/radical conditions.

Comment: it is nice for me to get some information about my question from your kind. but do you have any documents for me to refer to? because I need some documents in detail to start our work. please!! thanks  in advance ,friends!